# Will RestKit work on iOS9

Tags: nsurlconnection, restkit, afnetworking-2, nsurlsession, ios9

RestKit version(0.25.0) I am using in my app uses AFNetworking1.3.4 which in turn uses NSURLConnection. But Apple deprecated NSURLConnection in iOS9. Is there a latest RestKit version available that I can use in my iOS9 app or will the same version(0.25.0) work on iOS9 also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same version works on iOS 9 also.

But unless you are prepared to help update RestKit, you might consider it a red flag to depend on a library that requires deprecated iOS APIs, because who knows if those APIs will still be available in iOS 10?

It looks like [the latest work](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/2028) is focused on removing the AFNetworking dependency and using NSURLSession directly.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect NSURLConnection to be around for a long time to come, as it is very broadly used.  It will not, however, get any new features, in all likelihood.

Either way, it works fine in iOS 9.